# Hibernate criteria builder between predicate with abstract class type definition

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I want to use Hibernate's CriteriaBuilder between method which is defined as:

```
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate between(Expression<? extends Y> v, Y x, Y y)
```

I have the following abstract class, the important method is `toPredicate`.

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Path;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;

abstract public class RangeObject<T> {
    protected T from;
    protected T to;

    public RangeObject(T from, T to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public T getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public T getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    /**
     * Create a predicate for testing whether the second argument is
     * between the `from` and `to` values
     *
     * @param builder Criteria Builder instance
     * @param path    Attribute path from a bound type
     * @return between predicate
     */
    public Predicate toPredicate(
            CriteriaBuilder builder,
            Path<T> path
    ) {
        if (isSingleValue(from, to)) {
            return builder.equal(path, from);
        } else {
            return builder.between(path, from, to);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param from From value
     * @param to   To value
     * @return Whether parameters to this method match
     */
    abstract public boolean isSingleValue(T from, T to);
}
```

It has a parameter `Path<T>`.
Path interface is defined as `interface Path<X> extends Expression<X>` which as far as I understand should be compatible with `Expression<? extends Y>`.

I get the following error:

```
no suitable method found for between(javax.persistence.criteria.Path<T>,T,T)
```

I even tried changing the `toPredicate` method to:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder builder,
        Expression<? extends T> expression
) {
    if (isSingleValue(from, to)) {
        return builder.equal(expression, from);
    } else {
        return builder.between(expression, from, to);
    }
}
```

And I still get the same error:

```
no suitable method found for between(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<capture#1 of ? extends T>,T,T)
```

If I hardcode the type, it works ( this is an example of what works: )

```
import ...

abstract public class RangeObject {
    protected LocalDateTime from;
    protected LocalDateTime to;

    ...

    public Predicate toPredicate(
            CriteriaBuilder builder,
            Path<LocalDateTime> path
    ) {
        if (isSingleValue(from, to)) {
            return builder.equal(path, from);
        } else {
            return builder.between(path, from, to);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on method specification, arguments in `between` method should extends `Comparable`

```
<Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> Predicate between(Expression<? extends Y> v, Y x, Y y);
```

If you make `T` in your class specification extends `Comparable` it would works for Path and Expression both.

```
public abstract class RangeObject<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   protected T from;
   protected T to;
   .......
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Can't believe I havn't noticed that for hours. Thanks a lot!